# How do I start the REPL in a user defined namespace?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

Writing `(in-ns 'dbx)` to a file and loading it isn't changing the default namespace of the repl (using cygwin/console). The namespace is still `user=>`, not `dbx=>`.

```
vikrant[28] clj
Clojure 1.3.0
user=> (load-file "try1.clj")
#(Namespace dbx)
user=>
```

How can we start the REPL in a namespace defined in a script file?

Comment: (ns dbx)
(clojure.main/repl)
(in-ns 'dbx)
(clojure.core/use 'clojure.core)

Comment: Just a quick comment on formating. It's should be cleaner and easier to simply copy/paste the text in your cygwin console than taking a screen-shot of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java -cp .;clojure-1.3.0.jar; clojure.main -e \
"(ns dbx) (clojure.main/repl) (in-ns 'dbx) (clojure.core/use 'clojure.core)"
```

Answer (score 29):

Nowadays is `:repl-options {:init-ns foo.bar}`.

See https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj

Comment: @LincolnBergeson it still works for me using latest leiningen - version 2.7.1, with a brand new app project created with `lein new app`.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using [Leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) to build your project, then add this to your project's `project.clj` file:

```
(defproject test "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]]
  :main test.core)
```

In your `src/test/core.clj` file, add this to create a `test.core` namespace:

```
(ns test.core)

(defn -main [& args])
```

Next, build your project with Leiningen with `lein compile`. Then enter `lein repl` to invoke the REPL in your namespace. The REPL prompt will look like:

```
test.core=>
```

Comment: I recommend using Carlos's [more up-to-date answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24364816/109618).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Carlos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24364816/109618) suggesting `:repl-options {:init-ns foo.bar}`, I have also had success with adding `:dev {:main user}` to my profile.clj.

To give more context:

```
;; /foo/profile.clj
...
:main foo.core
:dev {:main user
      :source-paths ["dev"]}`
...

;; /foo/dev/user.clj
(ns user
  (:require
   [clojure.pprint :refer (pprint)]
   [clojure.repl :refer :all]
   [clojure.string :as str]
   [clojure.test :refer [run-tests run-all-tests]]
   [clojure.tools.namespace.repl :refer [refresh refresh-all]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using tools.deps one way would be to define an alias and execute some forms in it:

```
:aliases
      {:cursive {:main-opts ["-e" "(load \"de/sveri/getless/user\")"
                             "-e" "(de.sveri.getless.user/reset)"]}
```

This will load the `de.sveri.getless.user` namespace and execute the `de.sveri.getless.user.reset` function afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

`(ns dbx) 
(clojure.main/repl) 
(in-ns 'dbx) 
(clojure.core/use 'clojure.core)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a much better way to do this in recent Clojure versions:

`java -cp myapp.jar clojure.main -m myapp.core`