# How do i open a repl in a different namespace

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

Specifically with a leiningen uberjar.

```
java -cp myapp.jar clojure.main -r
```

gets me a repl but defaults to the user namespace
What do I need to do to get it to myapp's namespace?

```
java -cp myapp.jar clojure.main -e (in-ns myapp.core)
```

gives me clojure.lang.LispReader$ReaderException

*** Update ***
The ultimate goal is to simply run

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

and have a Clojure REPL in my app's namespace.
Every solution I've seen involves writing code on the command line that I want to put into my main method but can't seem to get running

```
(defn -main [&args]
  (clojure.main/main "-e" "(in-ns myapp.core)"))
```

completes/terminates immediately

Comment: Take a look at this, may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306157/to-start-repl-in-user-defined-namespace

Comment: The answers for that question are out of date, there are much better answers for the latest clojure version, and the highest voted answer assumes you are running lein, which is not valid for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java -cp myapp.jar clojure.main -m myapp.core`