# How to change to a namespace when calling clojure.main/repl

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using `clojure.main/repl` (see [the docs](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.main-api.html#clojure.main/repl)) and would like to automatically switch to a ns before the user has to type anything. But how?

`:init` doesn't seem to be able to solve my problem, or how to use it?

Please note that:

- I know about [this question here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306157/to-start-repl-in-user-defined-namespace).
- [This one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311286/how-do-i-open-a-repl-in-a-different-namespace).
- I'm using the repl from within `org.dipert.swingrepl`, so I'm not interested in the `:init-ns` option of lein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about `org.dipert.swingrepl` or why anyone would want to use it but it's quite simple to do it:

```
(clojure.main/repl :init #(in-ns 'my-favorite-namespace))
```

Comment: Indeed it works with `clojure.main/repl` but not with `swingrepl`. My guess is that `swingrepl` has a bug. The reason why swingrepl is useful is that my user can just double click the jar to have access to the REPL. Or do you now how to trigger a `cmd` launch on Windows to host `clojure.main/repl` after a simple double click (not a command in cmd please)?

Comment: I believe Fogus was playing around with the idea of a nrepl <-> cljs architecture, if you could start an nrepl server and bind `*in*` to a ring handler and `*out*` to the ring response you could have instant feedback from a browser repl web application. Another idea would be to use the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html]) java class to launch arbitrary commands like `lein repl`. Or just use make regular Windows link to Leiningen that executes the command with options.