# How to get `lein-repl` to use `user` instead of `main` for development purposes

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to set up a development version and a production version of my application using `leiningen` via the `project.clj`.

How can I have both? Because I have to comment out the `:main` part of my `project.clj` in order to get access to the development version when I use `lein repl`.

So I am using [stuartsierra/reloaded leiningen template](https://github.com/stuartsierra/reloaded) which has a nice development environment.

It comes with no `:main` key and when I added one that's when I stopped getting the development version of my project.

Instead of seeing

```
user=>
```

When I type `lein repl` I end up seeing my main, which is in the `jaribu` namespace

```
io.wakamau.jaribu=> ;; my main
```

The solution that seems to work is to comment out the `:main` part of the `project.clj`.

```
(defproject io.wakamau/jaribu "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "trying out pedestal and component"
  :url "https://github.com/kevinmungai/jaribu"
  :license {:name "TODO: Choose a license"
            :url "http://choosealicense.com/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [com.stuartsierra/component "0.3.2"]]
  :profiles {:dev
               {:dependencies [[org.clojure/tools.namespace 0.2.11"]
                               [com.stuartsierra/component.repl "0.2.0"]]
                :source-paths ["dev"]}
             :uberjar {:aot [io.wakamau.jaribu]}}
  :main ^{:skip-aot true} io.wakamau.jaribu
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0")
```

trying out

```
lein repl
```

results in:

```
io.wakamau.jaribu=>
```

when the `:main` is commented out:

```
(defproject io.wakamau/jaribu "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
   ...
  ;; :main ^{:skip-aot true} io.wakamau.jaribu
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0")
```

the result is:

```
user=>
```

I have to admit that I don't know much about using `leiningen`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify [`:repl-options {:init-ns io.wakamau.jaribu=>}`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L369) in `project.clj`. You can also specify constants for different environments in `profiles.clj`, e.g., `:dev {:main io.wakamau.jaribu}`. Also see [How do I start the REPL in a user defined namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306157/how-do-i-start-the-repl-in-a-user-defined-namespace).

Comment: It has helped, Thanks.

Comment: Though i needed to set the `:init-ns` to `user`.